# Intersection / subset of pandas string columns

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, graph-theory, intersection

I have a pandas data frame with payments of the following structure:

```
>> print(df)

id      time      amount      seller     buyer
-------------------------------------------------
1       07:01     16.00       Jack       Rose
2       07:03     14.00       Alice      Bob
3       07:05     95.00       Jim        Larry
...     ...       ...         ...        ...
9999    18:16     81.00       Rose       Alice
```

**How do I find the "closed-members" payments network from this?**

For example, if I would like to find a subset of the data which contains only payments that {Rose, Alice, Jim} made strictly between each other, then the below may work:

```
members = ['Rose', 'Alice', 'Jim']
df_subset = df[df.seller.isin(members) & df.buyer.isin(members)]
```

But how does one retrieve the largest such network?, i.e. not just for 3 people but for the maximum possible number of people in the data frame?

I already tried variations of the below:

```
df_subset = df[df.seller.isin(df.buyer.unique())]
df_subset = df_subset[df_subset.buyer.isin(df_subset.seller.unique())]
```

This is not successful, however, since afterwards `df_subset.seller.unique()` and `df_subset.buyer.unique()` are not the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

I believe in the end `df_subset.seller.unique()` and `df_subset.buyer.unique()` should be the same.

Comment: This is a graph theory problem and you can use networkx with subgraphs method.  If you added more complete data with expected results.  I am sure the Stack Overflow community can help.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I had the suspicion it wouldn't be as simple. Would you know what this specific kind of problem is called? I have some experience with networkx and would look myself.

Comment: You might find some set logic that would make it easier.  Best luck.

Comment: I posted one approach to a solution below (which worked for me). In the end it was not strictly necessary to use the networkx library, though it might have been easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution seems to work. I will provide a sandbox solution as it might become useful for others.

First, let's define a similar pandas data frame as in the question:

```
# generates strings to be used as names, e.g.: 'hlddldxhys'
def randomString(stringLength=10):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

# let's generate a set of 600 names
participants = [];
for k in range(600):
    participants.append(randomString())

# from the generated set, draw 1000 sellers and buyers
seller = np.random.choice(participants, 1000)
buyer = np.random.choice(participants, 1000)

# construct pandas data frame
df = pd.DataFrame([seller, buyer]).T
df.columns = ['seller', 'buyer']
```

Taking a look at resulting data frame `print(df)`:

```
     seller       buyer
----------------------------
0    bpzroghaxp  evvhhlbiys
1    qsopxbirgn  lwwljadfwg
2    cnllyrzjiz  opbvoodpgw
3    hkzafylzst  slfqtwdeak
...    ...        ...
999  natqsscnlk  ftvjvgtala
```

While some have hinted towards a solution (replies from PMende, Tal Avissar, and myself), it seems that it does work - but only **iteratively**, where with each iteration of `df = df[df.seller.isin(df.buyer.unique()) & df.buyer.isin(df.seller.unique())]` the sets of `df.seller.unique()` and `df.buyer.unique()` become more similar to each other. This is repeated until they are both the same (see last if-statement, followed by `break`):

```
while(True):
    df = df[df.seller.isin(df.buyer.unique()) & df.buyer.isin(df.seller.unique())]
    if len(df.seller.unique()) == len(df.buyer.unique()):
        if (np.sort(df.seller.unique()) == np.sort(df.buyer.unique())).all() == True:
            break
```

A final check confirms, both `df.seller.unique()` and `df.buyer.unique()` are of same length and also of same composition:

```
>> len(df.seller.unique()), len(df.buyer.unique())
(281, 281)

>> (np.sort(df.seller.unique()) == np.sort(df.buyer.unique())).all()
True
```

Below charts visualise how the sets of `df.seller.unique()` and `df.buyer.unique()` become similar to each other with each iteration of the loop:

[See also charts: visualisation of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXytq.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you looking for in the maximum number of people

```
a = df[df.seller].drop_duplicates()
b = df[df.buyer].drop_duplicates()
result = pd.concat([a,b])
```

Comment: Thanks Tal, but this did not return the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the following should do what you want:

```py
common_users = set(df["buyer"]).intersection(df["seller"])
df_subset = df[df["buyer"].isin(common_users) & df["seller"].isin(common_users)]
```

Comment: Thank PMende, but this does not seem to work. I tried something very similar: `common_users = np.array(np.intersect1d(df.seller.values, df.buyer.values).tolist())` and then as suggested by you: `df_subset = df[df.seller.isin(common_users) & df.buyer.isin(common_users)]`. However, the resulting sets `df_subset.seller.unique()` and `df_subset.buyer.unique()` are still different from each other.